# Ruby script to read the last filled cell in a column

Tags: ruby, excel, win32ole

i need a ruby code to read the column a and find where does the last filled cell in the column ends.In the image uploaded the last filled data is i in cell "A21". i need to know this cell address through ruby code. [image]

Comment: Are you using `win32ole` ? One more clarification I need - what do you mean by *i need to know this **cell address** through ruby code* ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Yes i am using Win32ole...please help

Comment: means i need to reach to the last cell with data and fetch the data from that cell ...as in the image my last data is i i need to get the cell address and the value of that cell.

Comment: **cell address** means - `(21,1)` for the last data `i`.. right ?

Comment: yes rakshit u r correct in ur understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do using the Ruby ***stdlib***  [`WIN32OLE`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html) .

```
require 'win32ole'

# create an instance of the Excel application object
excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
# make Excel visible
excel.visible = true
# open the excel from the desired path
wb=excel.workbooks.open("C:\\Users\\test.xlsx")
# get the first Worksheet
wbs= wb.Worksheets(1)
# value of the constants I picked up from 
# http://techsupt.winbatch.com/ts/T000001033005F9.html
rng = wbs.range("1:1").SpecialCells(11) # value of 'xlCellTypeLastCell' is 11
rng.value # => "i"
rng.address # => "$A$21"
# to get the row and column number
row,col = rng.row,rng.column
[row,col] # => [21,1]
```

Look at the MSDN documentation of [`SpecialCells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178148%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

You can get the value of `xlCellTypeLastCell` from the version of `MSExcel` installed in your pc. Just do `ALT+F11` -> `F2` -> search the constant there :

[image: constant value]

Comment: @anurag I learned a lot from your question to.. and Glad to help you out.

Comment: :my god u so aggressive..:)

Comment: @anurag No no... I am not..  :)

Comment: actually i dnt know how to vote for a question so didn't do it...sorry:) but serious thanks for ur superb and quick help

Comment: `rng = wbs.range("1:1").SpecialCells(11)`, does work, but if there are borders around empty cells, it will include the borders, is there a way to determine the last cell with a value in it, using ruby?

Answer (score 0):

try using 'spreadsheet' gem

```
book = Spreadsheet.open 'myexcel.xls';
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
last_value = nil
sheet1.each do |row|
  last_value = row[0].present? && row[0]
end
last_value
=>
"i"
```

Comment: if it is excel file then you have to use gem.

Comment: @SachinSingh `win32ole` is also helpful, without gem :)