# Unable to open Excel application on Windows 7 using Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, excel, win32ole

I used the below code that I got from a website and  once  I executed I just got a disc for a few seconds but the excel application did not open.

```
require 'win32ole'

excel = WIN32OLE::new('excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add # create a new workbook
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the Excel workbook visible, enable the `visible` option.

```
require 'win32ole'

excel = WIN32OLE::new('excel.Application')
# Make Excel visible
excel.visible = true
```

Look [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190877/ruby-script-to-read-the-last-filled-cell-in-a-column/22194156#22194156) too.